# Make custom radio control accessible to screen readers

Tags: html, reactjs, forms, radio-button, accessibility

I needed to create a radio control for selecting 1 of 12 pre-defined options. User's needed an overview of all possible options at a glance, and to see the full details of each option on hover/focus/select. There's a lot of detail for each option but they can be grouped together easily (AWS EC2 Instance Types).

Here's what I created:

[image: screenshot of form control, showing groups of radio options]

Except for `tabindex, :hover, :focus, :active`, the interaction is controlled by JavaScript. After simplifying, the markup looks like this:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <h3>General Purpose</h3>
    <!-- details... -->
    <div>
      <span>1x</span>
      <!-- others... -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>Accelerated Computing v2</h3>
    <!-- content... -->
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>Accelerated Computing</h3>
    <!-- content... -->
  </div>
</div>
```

It works for well-sighted keyboard/mouse users but I'm not sure how to adjust this input for screen readers.

As an additional wrinkle, we should read just the size & hourly price when previewing an option from the same group the user is already looking at, and I'm not sure how to do this either.

NB: You can only click "1x", "2x", etc. these are the only selectable elements, the highlight around the category is just a visual thing.

Thanks for reading! Can you help?

Comment: Which part is the custom radio button? The 3 categories or the 1x, 4x, etc? Or both?

Comment: @Chris the whole thing. You can only select 1 of the 12 options. The 3 categories are for visualisation purposes only, and you can only see the full details for 3 potential options at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the ["Radio Group" pattern](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#radiobutton) on the WAI-ARIA Authoring Practices 1.1.  You basically need a `role="radiogroup"` (with a label) around the entire container (the parent of your 12 `<div>`s) and then each radio button should have `role="radio"`.  (You'll also need `aria-checked` and possibly `aria-label` or `aria-labelledby` on each radio button, but that is explained in the pattern.)

Note that specifying these ARIA attributes only conveys the semantics of the object to screen readers.  It does **not** give you any **behavior** of a radio group.  That is, when the user selects one radio button, it's up to you (presumably via javascript) to unselect the previous button that was selected.

To answer your question about only reading part of the information, you can use `aria-hidden` on anything you don't want read, or you can specify an `aria-label` or `aria-labelledby` which will override any embedded text in child elements.  The example below uses `aria-labelledby` and points to the heading of each radio button so only that heading will be read when the screen reader tabs to the radio button.  However, hiding information from screen readers would fail accessibility compliance (WCAG) if the information is available to sighted users.  In your screenshot, if the cost per hour, the GPU, and other info is visible to sighted users but hidden from screen reader users, that would be bad.

Note also that you need to manage the keyboard focus yourself (javascript).  Only **one** of the radio buttons should have `tabindex="0"` and the others should have `tabindex="-1"`.  If the user presses the down arrow, the radio button that used to have `tabindex="0"` should now have `tabindex="-1"` and the newly focused radio button should have `tabindex="0"`.  The `aria-checked` attribute should match the tabindex so that the button with `tabindex="0"` has `aria-checked="true"` and the buttons with `tabindex="-1"` should have `aria-checked="false"`.

Here's a rough sample using your original code.  Note that the radio buttons are using `aria-labelledby` pointing to the headings, but this is not recommended because the cost per hour, GPU, etc will be hidden from screen reader users.

```
<div role="radiogroup" aria-label="your 12 options">
  <div role="radio" aria-labelledby="GeneralPurpose" tabindex="0" aria-checked="true">
    <h3 id="GeneralPurpose">General Purpose</h3>
    <!-- details... -->
    <div>
      <span>1x</span>
      <!-- others... -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div role="radio" aria-labelledby="AccComputing2" tabindex="-1" aria-checked="false">
    <h3 id="AccComputing2">Accelerated Computing v2</h3>
    <!-- content... -->
  </div>
  <div role="radio" aria-labelledby="AccComputing" tabindex="-1" aria-checked="false">
    <h3 id="AccComputing">Accelerated Computing</h3>
    <!-- content... -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Couple things: why is `tabindex="0"` on everything selectable bad? In your example, you added `role="radio"` to the categories, rather than the options (eg, "1x"), was this intentional?

Comment: That was based on your comment about the whole thing being treated as a radio button - that you can select only 1 of the 12.  I thought your "General Purpose" box was an entire button, and the "Accelerated Computing v2" box was the next button, and so on.  That's how my code example works.  Someone asked if you wanted the 1x buttons as a radio and it didn't sound like you did.  If the 1x buttons are supposed to be a radio, then you can still do what I suggested but instead of role="radio" on the big boxes, it's on the 1x boxes.  But you can't have a radio nested in a radio.

Comment: Regarding `tabindex`, you don't want every radio button as a separate tab stop.  You want the radio group as a whole to be one tab stop with the focus going to the selected radio button.  So only the selected radio button (`aria-checked="true"`) should have `tabindex="0"` and the other radio buttons in the group should have `tabindex="-1"`.